# what is the mapping between cert file, key file, pem file and ca file AND redis TLS parameters?

Tags: ssl, redis, tls1.2

I am using below commands:

> openssl req -new -newkey -keyout example.key

> openssl dhparam -out example.pem

I submit the csr (also generated by openssl not shown above) file to CA which reply with a text file named sighned certificate. This text file has 4 sections each section starts with ----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---- and ends with -----END CERTIFICATE------

Does the first section map to ROOT CERTIFICATE? Does the third section map to INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE? What the last section maps to?

I also use keytool to generate keystore.jks file. What is jks file and why it is needed?

Now in redis TLS [docs](https://redis.io/docs/manual/security/encryption/)

```
tls-cert-file /path/to/redis.crt
tls-key-file /path/to/redis.key
tls-ca-cert-file /path/to/ca.crt
tls-dh-params-file /path/to/redis.dh
```

What files I use to plugin in above settings?

What is the difference between tls-cert-file and tls-ca-cert-file?

Comment: JKS stands for Java KeyStore. It is a file, used in Java applications, for storing your public/private/... keys. You do not need a jks file for starting a Redis server with enabled TLS. But you will need one if you want to connect a Java application to a TLS Redis server. I do not know if that is the case.

Comment: There is java client web server app that accesses the TLS redis server remotely. Where jks file is used in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSR RESPONSE DATA**

If you have 4 files returned from the certificate signing request, then I would expect them to be as follows,

- Root CA public key (root.crt)
- Intermediate CA public key (intermediate.crt)
- Certificate public key (public.crt)
- Certificate private key (private.key)

The first 3 of these should have this format, representing a public key:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDZzCCAk+gAwIBAgIJAN7ZkzJkHq8DMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMCsxKTAnBgNV
BAMTIFNlbGYgU2lnb...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I would expect the 4th file to have a different format, representing a private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAnLLaBhMIKAjaeLiY8qrr2xbTI5RRDK0QVyoogv3Bebv6llGj
pwnNmIOpMg/a33skE1YY78beAq5WSag3lv/hFGNTXTGs7Y4vZRjL92KrSkZWC/Cc
6YlkDR5+6nkIcTpiSShDxfF4a4qozgV1QNkXn4Cp4G6um798Tr6aZRI1wWohAvLp
B1O09IraZVhLLk
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

For each public key, paste them into [the GoDaddy online certificate viewer](https://ssltools.godaddy.com/views/certDecoder). The output text will enable you to distinguish between the role of each certificate, to ensure that you've identified them correctly.

**APPLY CERTIFICATE FILES TO REDIS**

Then assign values for redis as follows. The `tls-cert-file` is exposed to redis clients, to represent the public part of the redis server's TLS identity. The `tls-ca-cert-file` is also exposed to clients, and represents the public part of the TLS identity for issuing authorities:

```
tls-cert-file = public.crt
tls-key-file = private.key
tls-ca-cert-file = trusted.crt
```

The `trusted.crt` file is a bundle file consisting of root and intermediate certificate authorities. It is formed by concatenating the root public key followed by the intermediate public key:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDZzCCAk+gAwIBAgIJAN7ZkzJkHq8DMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMCsxKTAnBgNV
BAMTIFNlbGYgU2lnb...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDjzCCAnegAwIBAgIUY0Or/jjq9tZav7mle1DOWyyomPUwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
BQAwMTEvMC0GA1UEAxMmU2VsZiBTaWduZWQgQ0EgZm9yIGF1dGhzYW1wbGVzLWRl
di5jb20wHhcNMjIwMzE3M...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**CERTIFICATE CREATION**

Sometimes it can be useful to create your own development certificates, to better understand the process, without requiring infrastructure. You can generate all 3 types of file using openssl. See [this script of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.developmentcertificates/blob/main/makecerts.sh) for an example.

I would aim to avoid JKS files. They are a Java specific layer on top of the PKI and a less portable concept. You should not need it to get redis working over TLS. Similarly, [dhparams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-agreement_protocol) is a more advanced option used for key agreement between client and server. You should not need this if you just want to secure redis via TLS.

**CERTIFICATE TRUST**

You also need to manage client connections to redis. They will need to trust the root and intermediate certificates also, but the exact way you configure this will depend on the technology stack of the client.

Trust can be established by either trusting the `trusted.ca.crt` file, or trusting both the `root.crt` and `intermediate.crt` files. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/developer-ssl-setup/) has some examples of configuring trust in clients.

Comment: Does the first section map to ROOT CERTIFICATE? Does the third section map to INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE? What the last section maps to?

Comment: What is the difference between tls-cert-file and tls-ca-cert-file?

Comment: I updated my answer on what to do with the returned files - double check this against your own setup though.

Comment: In my case openssl generates the private key (openssl req -new -newkey -keyout example.key). The CA response as mentioned in the question gives signed cert text has 4 sections each section starts with ----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---- and ends with -----END CERTIFICATE------. So in this case the first section is the root cert? the last 4rth section is the end cert or server cert and second to last (the third section) is intermediate cert?

Comment: and what the second section maps to?

Comment: There could be multiple intermediate CAs, in which case add them all to the trusted.crt file. You are in the best position to see what each cert represents, by pasting each cert into the onlne viewer link I provided. This will tell you the issuer of each cert, to allow you to see the trust chain. This will also allow you to distinguish the public.crt one, which you need to provide to redis in a different parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Refer from *redis-src/utils/gen-test-certs.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p tests/tls
openssl genrsa -out tests/tls/ca.key 4096
openssl req \
    -x509 -new -nodes -sha256 \
    -key tests/tls/ca.key \
    -days 3650 \
    -subj '/O=Redis Test/CN=Certificate Authority' \
    -out tests/tls/ca.crt
openssl genrsa -out tests/tls/redis.key 2048
openssl req \
    -new -sha256 \
    -key tests/tls/redis.key \
    -subj '/O=Redis Test/CN=Server' | \
    openssl x509 \
        -req -sha256 \
        -CA tests/tls/ca.crt \
        -CAkey tests/tls/ca.key \
        -CAserial tests/tls/ca.txt \
        -CAcreateserial \
        -days 365 \
        -out tests/tls/redis.crt
openssl dhparam -out tests/tls/redis.dh 2048
```

You can use this script to generate redis.crt, redis.key, ca.crt and redis.dh.